# Velocity Relative To A Vector

Tags: mathematics, vector, linear-algebra, direction, spaces

So I have a velocity vector *`b`* in world space and I have a "pointing" vector *`a`* in world space. I need to know how to make the velocity vector to be relative to the "pointing" vector. Better explanation in image below:

[image: The Problem]

So on the left you can see the vectors in world space, but on the right - vectors in *`a`* space. I need to get the vector *`b`* in the _`a`_space from the worldspace.

Comment: Rotate b with minus the angle from y-axis to a, in your left pictures? E.g top left, from y to a seems to be about 30 degrees. Rotate b by -30 degrees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solved this in kind of simple way.
As I had the pointing vector(which in my specific case was `y`, but it doesn't matter that much) and I found out that I can actually get another vector out here. So I made a vector plane of `x` and `y` vectors. Than I did `x.cross(y)` and obtained `z` vector. Than I made those vectors 4D by setting `w` to be 0. After that I created a new matrix and plugged each of those vectors into the matrix - `x` into column 0, `y` into comun 1 and `z` into comlumn 2. In the result I had a transformation matrix which I could use as multiplier for the velocity vector and obtained velocity relative to the vector.
Unfourtunately, I should say that vector to vector-space conversion requires 2 vectors. Fourtunately, I had 2:)

Answer (score 1):

you can just convert the coodinates.

to do this, you have to use the normalized `â` as an base vector for the new coodinating system then use the 90º rotated `norm(a.y,-a.x)` as another base.

lets name they as `e1` and `e2`.

now you can express your vector `b` as an linear combination of `e1` and `e2` with the linear system of equations:

```
b = m*e1+n*e2

b.x = m*e1.x+n*e2.x
b.y = m*e1.y+n*e2.y
```

solve for `m` and `n` and the vector `(m,n)` is your `b` in `a` coodinates

Comment: But I have 3D vectors in my case(propably forgot to mention). How would I do it with 3D vectors? Oh, and that means that:
`m = b / e1`;
`n = b / e2`;
`o = b / e3`
right?
Yeah, I still need to know the step where you rotate it by 90 degrees in 3D setup.

Answer (score 0):

The “velocity in **`a`** space” can be broken down in two vectors, one that is the same direction as **`a`**, and one that is perpendicular to **`a`**.

The first vector has direction **`u`** and size `su`, computed as follows:

```
u = normalize(a)
su = dot(u, b)
```

The perpendicular vector has direction **`v`** and size `sv`:

```
v = normalize(b - su * a)
sv = dot(v, b)
```